# Website keep showing IIS Windows Server page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I had configured our wordpress website on the IIS Server.
We have a domain name with SSL, I had configured (site binding with mysql URLs) my website from local URL to live domain URL.
I am also redirecting http to https by using the below rules into wp.config file:

```
<rules>
                <rule name="Incomegenius.net" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
</rules>
```

With the help of the above redirection, We can able to properly redirect from http to https URL.
But, When I am trying to access our website URL without any http or https (only website name), It will redirect to IIS Windows Server page Why?
So, I want, when somebody types only website URL (e.g. google.com) into the address bar without http or https, so it will not redirect to IIS windows Server page.

Is there any more redirections I need to set? or what else need to do, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will automatically prepend a http(s):// to the name. However, I suspect you're using an older browser that automatically prepends http://www. ...this will fail as your rule won't match subdomains, thus, you end up on the IIS default page. Change your redirect action to this:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)incomegenius.net$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://incomegenius.net{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

This will redirect to the non-www. HTTPS URL regardless of the subdomain used.

Comment: I have updated with the above one, but still, it won't work. Can I change my website URL to https://www.websitename.net instead of https://websitename.net?  into the site URL.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a WordPress site so you can simply change the URL in `/wp-admin/` under Settings → General and modify the WordPress Address and Site URL to https://www.websitename.net instead of https://websitename.net

Comment: I did changed website url from https://sitename.net to https://www.sitename.net , but still when I am trying to type only the sitename on our address bar whitout http or www, it will still taking IIS Windows Server default page. And when I typing the whole URL as it is like https://www.sitename.net on address bar then and then only it will reflect on our website. I want, When somebody type url as sitename only, still it will redirect on our website prepends https://www automatically. When this will happened? Either this is redirection issue or may be site binding issue on IIS Server.

Comment: How to redirect all URL's (i.e. http://sitename, http://www.sitename) to our main url https://www.sitename.net (this is our main url with SSL)

Comment: Issue resolved through site binding on IIS Server. Thanks